# How to use custom JSP tags in a development environment

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, sysdeo

My question is fairly simple, and I think it should have a decently easy answer. Google has failed me, however, so I turn to you!

I have a multi-project setup where `ProjectA` is a web application that depends on `ProjectB`. `ProjectB` is built into a JAR file with a `/META-INF/tags` directory, which is then included in the `ProjectA` WAR file and run on Tomcat 8. When the project is built thus, everything works as expected.

My problem arises in development. I am using a locally modified version of the [Sysdeo Tomcat Plugin](http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html), which seems to work just fine in most cases. The issue is that when the web application `ProjectA` is deployed, `ProjectB` is simply included on the classpath via the `bin` directory generated by Eclipse. Since it is not a JAR file, the `/META-INF/myTags.tld` is not found in the default configuration. I got around this hiccup using the `<JarScanner scanAllDirectories='true' />` option in the `<Context>` block. Awesome.

The TLD file lists tags which point to locations in the `/META-INF/tags` directory, as such:

```
<tag-file>
  <name>pane</name>
  <path>/META-INF/tags/pane.tag</path>
</tag-file>
```

But at runtime, I get:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: File [/META-INF/tags/pane.tag] not found
```

I expect I'm just missing some configuration for Jasper here, but I can't seem to find it. I appreciate your help, and if I can provide any more details, please just ask!

Comment: I know this may not be what you are looking for, but I've found it easier to just include the tag files in each project's /META-INF/tags/ folder.  I know it creates duplicate copies of the tag files but the underlying Java code is only built into the .jar file once.  I have ProjectA, ProjectB, & ProjectC which all depend on tags built into the ProjectD jar (which is included in ProjectsA-C.  The only way I've found to handle it is to have my tags.tld tags in each project.

Comment: @Shaggy - That sounds pretty dirty, but I appreciate the input! I would have thought this was a very common problem that I'm just missing the "elegant" answer to, but it's seeming more and more like kludging is the only way to a solution. I wonder if using Eclipse's WTP is just as bad?

Comment: That's what I use, and it works great for linking the .jar file project with the web modules for debugging purposes (amongst other benefits).  I still have not found a way to point the dynamic web modules to the tags in another project.  +1 for the question as I am now interested if anyone else knows.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can try adding the ProjectB jar or war in the classpath of META-INF of ProjectA which will give the apt result